# Add TableAdapter in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, tableadapter

I want to add TableAdapter in my project for making RDLC report, but when I choose to using the existing stored procedure named "RPT_PRDB001-2", the source columns that I select in stored procedure does not appear (looks like the picture :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx7S3.png).
Can you help me with this issue? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

In the picture, it appears you have entered the name of a SELECT stored procedure, but on the right of the form it is showing an empty list of parameters for an INSERT stored procedure.

Does your stored procedure have any parameters?

If you click the name of the SELECT procedure, you will probably see the list of column names appear to the right.

EDIT: If you have a DataSet already or can add one somehow, then you can right-click on it in the DataSet Designer window, and choose Add... Query... and choose Existing Stored Procedure. This will give you a slightly different window (see screenshot below). Maybe that window will show you more information.

[image: Add Query Wizard with existing stored procedure]

Comment: yup, i have one parameter. Sorry for uploading the wrong picture, I've edited the link. Kindly check.. Thanks @scottHutchinson

Comment: If your stored procedure using temp tables, then the link below might lead you to a solution. Otherwise, if the stored procedure uses SELECT *, then change it to use SELECT columnName1, columnName2, etc.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1099614.aspx?TableAdapter+can+t+see+stored+proc+returned+fields+when+using+temp+table